# Simulator, to send request - response and open TCP connection

Tags: c++, python, simulator, tcpclient

I  have to write a simulator, which send a requests for registration and after getting response from other device, it opens a TCP session/connection between each other. I have to start from scratch. I can write it in python or C++ i think. Can anyone help me with few references from where I can start working in right direction and do this successfully.?

Thanks
Akansha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic Python TCP/IP Client and Server tutorial can be found [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/socket/tcp.html)

Comment: Yaa I am much comfortable with python. So i will try this . Thanks Eduardo

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and do this in C++

Comment: This looks like good option. I will read this and its tutorial. Thanks Vid